# Возможно ли игнорировать участок кода в зависимости от платформы?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

В свете того, что C# используется много на каких платформах, кусок старого кода можно так или иначе использовать на них на всех, но если программа на компе поддерживает куски подтянутые в WPF проект из WinForms, ASP на них ругается.

Существует ли механизм позволяющий игнорировать этот участок кода в зависимости от платформы?

Надеюсь вопрос корректно задан.

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду проблемы при подключении готовых библиотек или проектов написанных для одной платформы  в проект для другой платформы, то нет, так не выйдет, у каждой платформы есть свои заморочки и зависимости, которые не всегда совместимы с другтми. Я бы на вашем месте выделил в отдельную библиотеку нужный и независимый от платформы код, и ее подключил бы во все остальные проекты. Если же остальные проекты это просто легаси-наследство, поддерживать и развивать которые не планируется, то просто вырезать оттуда нужный код.

Comment: Вроде, через препроцессор можно игнорировать участки кода. У самих майрософт это в исходних встречал.

Comment: Это имеется ввиду думаю https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if

Comment: @adrug да эта вещь меня как раз и интересовала. Я уже сам разобрался, но все равно вам спасибо. Не умею правильно пользоваться сайтом, я ведь могу за подходящий ответ плюсик поставить или что-то подобное?

Comment: @Сергей да, но лучше думаю будет если вы предложите свой вариант решения собственной проблемы в качестве ответа!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решено. Все оказалось до боли просто и очевидно. нужно было просто вынести кусок платформозависимого кода в отдельное место вот и всё)

ну или использовать директивы на подобии #if